onClick event on Grafana geomap
Is there a way to make it possible to click on geomap marker and it will trigger dashboard variable to change, so other panel will display the information selected by me? I have tried it with datalink, and it works well, but is there a way to do this without popup window? I want to disable this window and make it only by clicking the map
